# Extension .exe needed for WSL! How to write a generic script? (WSL, Cygwin, Linux, MacOS)

Tags: linux, macos, shell, cygwin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use `docopts` in my Shell scripts.  That works nicely from Cygwin.

I just need to be sure that `docopts` is present, at the top of my scripts:

```
command -v docopts > /dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "docopts not found"; exit 2; }
...
parsed="$(docopts -h "$help" -V "$version" : "$@")"
eval "$parsed"
```

But, in WSL, it needs the extension `.exe` to find the program to launch.

Should I adapt all my scripts this way?

```
DOCOPTS=
command -v docopts > /dev/null 2>&1 && DOCOPTS=docopts
command -v docopts.exe > /dev/null 2>&1 && DOCOPTS=docopts.exe
[ -z "$DOCOPTS" ] && { echo >&2 "docopts not found"; exit 2; }
...
parsed="$($DOCOPTS -h "$help" -V "$version" : "$@")"
eval "$parsed"
```

Or is there a much **smarter way** to do that, so that my scripts will work in any environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to install `docopts` in WSL rather than attempting to use the Cygwin `docopts.exe` version.  That will (a) allow you to use the same config (without an `.exe` extension) in both, and (b) likely be more compatible.  I've noticed and heard of a few idiosyncrasies when attempting to use Cygwin executables inside of WSL.   WSL does a *great* job of providing the compatibility layer between Linux and Windows EXE, but Cygwin does some "magic" that might cause issues.

Comment: This is indeed the right way. Worked, by following installation doc on https://github.com/docopt/docopts.

Answer (score 0):

This looks good. Suggestion would be to have it configured based on the "uname".If uname is "cywgin" then DOCOPTS= docopts or docopts.exe based on WSL.This would be easier to maintain and would be readable.
Regards